# Borland Builder 2007 - Making a TForm window transparent

Tags: c++, c++builder

Does anybody know how to make a TForm background (just the client area, any components on the form will not be included) transparent.

I can see that there is a GlassFrame section which can be used to do this by setting the SheetOfGlass setting to true. However this is not transparent enough, the form needs to be completly transparent.

Please any advice or tips would be great.

Thanks

Comment: Can you use `AlphaBlend` and [`AlphaBlendValue`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/XE2/en/Forms.TForm.AlphaBlendValue)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TForm has `TransparentColor` and `TransparentColorValue` properties.  Set the `Color` property to a value that does not appear in any child components, then set the `TransparentColor` property to `true` and the `TransparentColorValue` property to match the `Color` property.